# TypeError: calculateGstBaseOnInput is not a function

Tags: node.js

```
exports.test = function(req,res,next)
{
    wait.launchFiber(calculateGstBaseOnInput(req,res)); 
}
var calculateGstBaseOnInput = Fiber(function(req,res){
    console.log("welcome");
    for(var item of req.body.so_items) {
        req.productid = item.productid;
        req.qty = item.qty;
        wait.for(getItemDetail,req,res);
        wait.for(getCartItems,req,res);
        wait.for(calculateGST,req,res);
}};
```

ERROR :

> TypeError: calculateGstBaseOnInput is not a function
>       at exports.test (D:\node\app\addorder.js:47:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (D:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Query._callback (D:\node\app\addorder.js:41:21)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
>       at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
>       at Query.EofPacket (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
>       at Parser.write (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)

Comment: Move the whole `exports.test` block below the `var calculateGstBaseOnInput` block. Thats a scoping issue.

Comment: calculateGstBaseOnInput = Fiber(function(req,res){
    console.log("welcome");
    for(var item of req.body.so_items) {
        req.productid = item.productid;
        req.qty = item.qty;
        wait.for(getItemDetail,req,res);
        wait.for(getCartItems,req,res);
        wait.for(calculateGST,req,res);

     }
});
exports.test = function(req,res,next)
{
    wait.launchFiber(calculateGstBaseOnInput(req,res)); 
} changed.still the same error.